# Word found unreadable content in .docx, Adding xml in document template using docx4j

Tags: docx4j

First i have created a document template file and added a xml to MS Document from XML Mapping Pane of Developer tab.

Xml used for content binding.

```
<employee>
<name></name>
</employee>
```

Below mentioned method is used to write xml into doc template. Where this method takes documentForm(result doc file), xmlSchemaFilePath(created xml path), templateForm(templete file) as arguments.

```
 public String fillXMLBasedForm(String documentForm, String xmlSchemaFilePath, String templateForm)
        throws Exception {

    try {
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(templateForm));
        FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(xmlSchemaFilePath);
        Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML);
        Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new FileOutputStream(new File(documentForm)), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return documentForm;
}
```

Once i open the generated document file then got "Word found unreadable content.." popup. once i proceed as trusted document then found no issue in content because for testing purpose written only single string to it.

```
XML added via code. 

<employee>
<name>Vivek Singh</name>
</employee>
```

Comment: Please try again, using an up to date docx4j (8.1.5 or 8.1.6 at the time of writing)

Comment: @JasonPlutext what are the minimum jars to add because i can see number of Docx4j. https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.docx4j

Comment: See https://www.docx4java.org/downloads.html

Comment: Thanks @JasonPlutext, issued is resolved by using docx4j(v8.1.5).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the minimum required jars that I have used to solve this problem.

```
commons-compress-1.18
commons-io-2.6
docx4j-core-8.1.5
docx4j-JAXB-Internal-8.1.5
docx4j-openxml-objects-8.1.5
slf4j-api-1.7.26
xalan-interpretive-8.0.0
xalan-serializer-8.0.0
```